# Given a group $G$ and $x \in G$, can we say that $x^t$ and $x^p,\forall t,p \in \mathbb{Z}$ are commutative with respect to group operation?

Tags: group-theory

Given a group $G$ and $x \in G$, can we say that $x^t$ and $x^p,\forall t,p \in \mathbb{Z}$ are commutative with respect to group operation?

This seems to me to be the case, as the cyclic group is commutative.

Comment: It's true by the (generalized) associative property, which allows you "to move" the brackets.

Comment: @Mathtask Note that this property is still valid for some binary operators that are not associative. This weaker form of associativity is called **power associativity**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_associativity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a bit more machinery, for a fixed $x\in G$, we consider the map $\eta_x:\mathbb{Z}\to G$ given by $$\eta_x(n)= x^n$$

Since $\eta_x$ is a group homomorphism and $\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic, then the image: $$\langle x\rangle = \{g\in G:\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}(g=x^n)\}$$ is also cyclic, hence abelian.

Answer (score 2):

We have that $x^t x^p = x^{t + p}$ by associativity. But $x^{t + p} = x^{p + t}$ by the fact that addition is commutative, and $x^{p + t} = x^p x^t$ by associativity again, so yes, $x^{t}x^p = x^p x^t$ in any group.

Comment: Exactly what I thought, is that sometimes it seems to be so trivial that it becomes difficult. Thank you so much @stillconfused

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\begin{align}
x^tx^p&=x^{t+p}\tag{1}\\
&=x^{p+t}\\
&=x^px^t,\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

where $(1)$ and $(2)$ are explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2199421/104041).